# CalcXPosValue function in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

I'm porting Delphi 7 code to Delphi XE2. In a TChart I need to call the axis CalXPosValue function. Calling it is no problem, but the return value is not correct (and quite different from what the function in Delphi 7 returns). This is true both for the Windows 32-bit as for the 64-bit version.
Anybody seen this problem? Found a solution?

Comment: Please specify what TeeChart version are you using. Is it the version shipped with the IDE? With the Update at Embarcadero (http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28780)? Or a Pro version (which exact version)? Also please specify with what series have you reproduced this. A simple example project is always very helpful.